# onClick backgroundColor change

Tags: css, dart, dart-html

im starting with dart and i got my first issue.

I wanted to make coloring Rows when some1 click on it.

Default i got backgroundColor white, when i click it changes to yellow, but when i click while it's yellow, it doesn't change again to white

Code:

```dart
 void changeText(MouseEvent event) {
  if(querySelector("#Column_1").style.backgroundColor == 'Yellow')
    querySelector("#Column_1").style.backgroundColor = 'White';

  else querySelector("#Column_1").style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
}
```

Comment: Do you want it in jquery or javascript?? [Check](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/N4heN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are returned lowercase even when you set them uppercased. The comparsion fails if they are not the same.

```
void changeText(MouseEvent event) {
  var col = querySelector('#Column_1'); 
  if(col.style.backgroundColor.toLowerCase() == 'white') {
    col.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  } else {
    col.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
}
```

I don't know why I didn't get any value back previously from the style attribute, but this works for me now.

I would suggest to use CSS and classes instead anyway.

When you put this in the `<head>` of your HTML or into your CSS file if you use one

```dart
<style>
  .isSelected {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

and change your `textChange` method to

```dart
void changeText(MouseEvent event) {
  var col = querySelector('#Column_1').classes.toggle("isSelected");
}
```

you should get your desired effect.

Comment: I updated my answer. The previous suggestion is still the preferred one.